# Infinite number of poles in a domain of a meromorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\in \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and $f$ be meromorphic. Let $\gamma$ be a simple closed path in $U$ and let $D$ be the interior of $\gamma$ in $U$. Also suppose there are no zeros on the trace of the path. Using this I can prove that there can be only finitely many zeros of $f$ in $D$ which is clearly a bounded domain. Now what if the set $P=${$z\in D|z$ is a pole of $f$} was infinite? Then clearly $P$ would have an accumulation point in $\overline D$. Can this be possible for a meromorphic function? I feel like it cannot since it would not be possible to find any disk in $D$ that does not contain a pole so it cannot be analytic in $D$. Can someone give me a proper answer if possible it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: *Question for you to answer* Is the set $1,1/2,1/3,\ldots$, discrete in $(0,1)$?

Comment: If $f$ had an accumulation point of poles, $1/f$ would have an accumulation point of zeros. What does that tell you?

Comment: @ChipHurst Then $1/f$ has to be identically zero right? I see

Comment: @PedroTamaroff ya . What happened to your answer? the second comment answers this question right?

Comment: @Heisenberg correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(z) = {\sin (1/z)}^{-1}$$ on the positive real half plane $\mathbf H$, say. The set of poles of $f$ is indeed discrete *in* $\mathbf H$, although the poles accumulate at $0$. By definition, $f(z)$ is thus meromorphic.

Comment: Ya but in a bounded domain the poles will be finite right?

Comment: @Heisenberg No. You could just take $B(0,1)\cap\bf H$ and use my example .

Comment: There are infinitely many zeros of $f$ in $B(0,1)∩H$?

Comment: Not zeros, poles.

Comment: $1/\sin(1/z)$ is not meromorphic because there is an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: @ChipHurst Meromorphic **where**? =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff $f(z) = 1/\sin(1/z)$ is not meromorphic in any open ball about $z = 0$.

Comment: @ChipHurst Sure. But I am taking $\Re z>0$.

Comment: Right. OP is taking the closure of the domain though. I need to reread the question and let it soak in my head for awhile.